# Push notification installation in server

Tags: php, push-notification

I'm trying to get push notification for all the three mobile platform(Android, iOS, Windows phone). I tried looking for many push notification service. like pushwoosh etc... But all have sdk for mobile. Are there any open source that I can use in my server so that it pushed notification for all three platforms. I'm new to this concept. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: UrbanAirship is not free but good if you want to push to all at once.

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called **pushd** (https://github.com/rs/pushd) that you  might be interested in. It supports GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for Android and APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) and also Microsoft's push service.

pushd is a nodejs project that exposes an easy to use JSON/http interface. There is fantastic debugging/logging options.

EDIT: Microsoft has a service ([Notification Hubs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj927170.aspx)) that works on all devices which is free for 500 devices. Facebook also recently bought [Parse.com](https://parse.com/) which provide a similar service, although not free.